# How do i get the name/id of a folium marker to send to a python function on a FLASK app

Tags: python, flask, folium

I created a simple map using folium, and I added a layer with a bunch of markers that represent the location of some weather stations.

I would like to be able to click on one of the markers, get it's name/id and send that to a python function, that will then plot some parameters from that weather station. Ideally, I would like to display that image directly on a popup.

I am try to build a FLASK app to do it, and I believe I am in the right direction, but I am failing to call my python function. Also, I am not sure my template is doing anything.

My code so far (for this example, I simplified my python function to only create a simple .txt file):

```
import folium,branca,requests
from branca.element import Element
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from folium.plugins import LocateControl
from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def map():    
    start_coords = (38.7088, -9.1576)

    folium_map = folium.Map(location=start_coords, zoom_start=8,max_bounds=True,height="100%",zoom_control=False)

    fig=branca.element.Figure(height="100%",width='100%')
    fig.add_child(folium_map)

    folium.plugins.Fullscreen(position='bottomleft').add_to(folium_map)

    e=folium.LatLngPopup2()
    folium_map.add_child(e)

    LocateControl(strings={'drawMarker':'False'}).add_to(folium_map)

    ft_grp=folium.map.FeatureGroup(name='Meteo Stations - last 24H',show=False)

    rsp=requests.get('https://api.ipma.pt/open-data/observation/meteorology/stations/stations.json')
    codes=rsp.json()
    
    template = '''
        function handleMarkerClick(markerId) {
            // Send an AJAX request to the server with the marker's ID
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/plot_station",
                data: JSON.stringify({ id: markerId }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response.message);
                }
            });
        }

        // Iterate through markers and attach the click event
        var markers = document.querySelectorAll('.leaflet-marker-icon');
        markers.forEach(function(marker) {
            marker.addEventListener('click', function() {
                // Extract the marker's ID from the marker's DOM element
                var markerId = marker.getAttribute('data-id');
                handleMarkerClick(markerId);
            });
        });
    '''
    
    for ia,cd in enumerate(codes):
        if ia==0:
            name= cd['properties']['localEstacao']
            id= cd['properties']['idEstacao']
            coord= cd['geometry']['coordinates']
            popup = folium.Popup(id, max_width=150)
            marker=folium.Marker(
                location=[coord[1],coord[0]],
                popup=popup,
                id=str(id)
            ).add_to(ft_grp)
        
     
    map_id=folium_map.get_name()
    e = Element(template)
    html = folium_map.get_root()
    html.script.get_root().render()
    # Insert new element or custom JS
    html.script._children[e.get_name()] = e  
     
    folium_map.add_child(ft_grp)
    folium.LayerControl().add_to(folium_map)

    folium_map.save('test.html')
    return fig._repr_html_()


@app.route('/plot_station', methods=['POST'])
def plot_station():
    data = request.get_json()
    marker_id = data.get('id')
    print('aaa')

    if marker_id:
        # Use marker_id to perform actions, e.g., create a file
        filename = f"{marker_id}.txt"
        with open(filename, 'w') as fid:
            fid.write("Marker clicked!")

    return jsonify({"message": "Marker click handled successfully"})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I don't have a lot of experince with flask or javascript but if someone could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Thank you